# How to paste columns together only for rows with specific string in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df1):

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c('uniqA', 'uniqB', 'unknown', 'uniqC', 'unknown'))
```

I want to paste var1 and var2 columns only where var2 is "unknown" so that I get the resulting dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c('uniqA', 'uniqB', 'unknown', 'uniqC', 'unknown'),
                  var3 = c('uniqA', 'uniqB', 'c_unknown', 'uniqC', 'e_unknown'))
```

I only know how to paste columns together with all patterns:

```
df1$var3 = paste(df1$var1,"_",df1$var2)
```

I attempted this which gave me "TRUE" or "FALSE" and still pasted all patterns together:

```
df1$var3=paste(df1$var1,"_",grepl("unknown", df1$var2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You were close, use `ifelse` to do a vectorized conditional.

```r
paste0(ifelse(grepl("unknown", df1$var2), paste0(df1$var1, "_"), ""), df1$var2)
# [1] "uniqA"     "uniqB"     "c_unknown" "uniqC"     "e_unknown"
```

Comment: (I was thinking more of a *pattern* of `"unknown"` than the *literal*. As @akaDrHouse shows, equality works fine. My answer here does not require `grepl` if indeed it is always a literal equality.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ifelse()`

```
df1$var3 <- ifelse(df1$var2 == "unknown",
                   paste0(df1$var1,"_",df1$var2),
                   df1$var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result can be obtained in two steps (even if I'm sure that someone will realize it a more immediate manner).

The first step is to assign `var2` to `var3`

```
df1$var3 <- df1$var2
```

The sedond step is to modify only rows that match the condition on `var2`

```
 df1$var3[df1$var2 == "unknown"]  <- paste(df1$var1[df1$var2 == "unknown"], 
                                        df1$var2[df1$var2 == "unknown"], sep = "_")
```

The result is what expected:

```
    df1
  var1    var2      var3
1    a   uniqA     uniqA
2    b   uniqB     uniqB
3    c unknown c_unknown
4    d   uniqC     uniqC
5    e unknown e_unknown
```

Hope it can help!